# Error parsing data error in org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I have an error with my `JSON`,
`JsonObject` cannot release the `JsonArray`,

Okay this is my logcat.

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-18 18:38:17.079 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for isi
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at baru.azoel.ayomuncak.DetailBerita$AmbilDetailBerita$1.run(DetailBerita.java:91)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
08-18 18:38:17.082 31156-31156/baru.azoel.ayomuncak W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

column "isi"in my database I use field text not varchar,
ok this is my DetailBerita.Java

```
package baru.azoel.ayomuncak;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import baru.azoel.ayomuncak.Koneksi.ImageLoaderBerita;
import baru.azoel.ayomuncak.Koneksi.JSONParserBerita;

public class DetailBerita extends Activity {
    public ImageLoaderBerita imageLoader;
    {
        imageLoader = new ImageLoaderBerita(null);
    }

    JSONArray string_json = null;
    String idberita;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParserBerita jsonParser = new JSONParserBerita();
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id_berita";
    public static final String TAG_JUDUL = "judul";
    public static final String TAG_ISI = "isi";
    public static final String TAG_GAMBAR = "gambar";
    private static final String url_detail_berita =
            "https://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/detailBerita.php?";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_berita);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        idberita = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "id_berita = " + idberita,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new AmbilDetailBerita().execute();

    }
    class AmbilDetailBerita extends AsyncTask<String, String,
            String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetailBerita.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu ... !");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params1 = new
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params1.add(new
                        BasicNameValuePair("id_berita",idberita));
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_detail_berita, "GET", params1);
                string_json = json.getJSONArray("berita");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView)
                                findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        TextView judul = (TextView)
                                findViewById(R.id.judul);
                        //TextView detail = (TextView)
                        findViewById(R.id.detail);
                        TextView isi = (TextView)
                                findViewById(R.id.content);
                        try {
                            // ambil objek member pertama dari JSON Array
                            JSONObject ar =
                                    string_json.getJSONObject(0);
                            String judul_d = ar.getString(TAG_JUDUL);
                            String isi_d = ar.getString(TAG_ISI);
                            String url_detail_image = ar.getString(TAG_GAMBAR);
                            judul.setText(judul_d);
                            isi.setText(isi_d);


//                            imageLoader.DisplayImage(ar.getString(TAG_GAMBAR),thumb_image);
                            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                    .load(url_detail_image)
                                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                                    .into(thumb_image);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my JSONParserBerita.Java

```
public class JSONParserBerita {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    public JSONParserBerita() {
    }
    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " +
                    e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

when I test my `JSON` in `PHP` its work, but in java not work,
in l[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fm2u.jpg)

what can I do?
this is my PHP code

```
<?php
$kd="";
include "kon.php";

$kd = $_GET['idberita'];
if(isset($_GET['id_berita'])){
 $kd=$_GET['id_berita'];
}
      $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from berita berita where id_berita='".$kd."'");
$json  = '{"berita": [';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query)) {

//tanda kutip dua (") tidak diijinkan oleh string json, 
//maka akan kita replace dengan karakter `
//strip_tag berfungsi untuk menghilangkan tag-tag html pada string  

$char = '"';

$json .= '{"id_berita":"'.$row['id_berita'].'",
"id_pos":"'.$row['id_pos'].'",
"judul":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row['judul'])).'",
"isi":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row['berita'])).'",
"gambar":"https://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/images/'.$row['gambar_berita'].'"},';
}

// buat menghilangkan koma diakhir array
$json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);

$json .= ']}';

// print json
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: Logcat itself clearly shows that you are getting wrong response with the <br> tag in Java. So please ask to JAVA developer to check the web service response and return right JSON in response. I have checked your web service response and it returns below response which throws error. 
Notice: Undefined index: idberita in /storage/ssd2/685/1759685/public_html/detailBerita.php on line 5
{"berita": [{"id_berita":"1", "id_pos":"1", "judul":"Penutupan terakhir", "isi":"terjadi ledakan yang mencengankan wadaww", "gambar":"https://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/images/morosari.jpg"}]}

Comment: there is something in your response with <br> ask back end developer to remove that it will work.

Comment: In your response there is some html tag is coming with <br> which is not paracable json ..please check the response

Comment: Means I need to fix in which part? in java or in my web service?

Comment: oke i will show my php for json,, where is my fault?

Comment: your response contains <br> tag..so it cant convert to JSONObject
error in line:91